# Autohide a Menu (WPF)

Tags: wpf, user-controls, wpf-controls

Is there a simple property that enables the menu class to autohide after a set number of seconds? I've searched MSDN but am unable to find a suitable property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default Menus don't support this, but by little modifications, you can easily implement this behavior.

For example:

```
public class AutoHideMenuItem : MenuItem
{
    DispatcherTimer timer;

    private Int32 _autoHideDelay;
    public Int32 AutoHideDelay
    {
        get
        {
            return _autoHideDelay;
        }
        set
        {
            _autoHideDelay = value;
            timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(AutoHideDelay);
        }
    }

    public AutoHideMenuItem()
    {
        MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(AutoHideMenuItem_MouseMove);
        ContextMenuOpening += new ContextMenuEventHandler(AutoHideMenuItem_ContextMenuOpening);
        SubmenuClosed += new RoutedEventHandler(AutoHideMenuItem_SubmenuClosed);

        timer = new DispatcherTimer(DispatcherPriority.Normal, Dispatcher);
        timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(AutoHideDelay);
        timer.Stop();

        timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);
    }

    void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsSubmenuOpen && !IsMouseOver)
        {
            IsSubmenuOpen = false;
        }
    }

    void AutoHideMenuItem_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        timer.Stop();
        timer.Start();
    }

    void AutoHideMenuItem_ContextMenuOpening(object sender, ContextMenuEventArgs e)
    {
        timer.Start();
    }

    void AutoHideMenuItem_SubmenuClosed(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        timer.Stop();
    }
}
```

Can be used like:

```
            <local:AutoHideMenuItem Header="File" AutoHideDelay="3">
                <MenuItem Header="New"></MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Header="Open"></MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Header="Close"></MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Header="Exit"></MenuItem>
            </local:AutoHideMenuItem>
```

Which will close this menu after 3 seconds. Of course its rough code and you will need to make changes to it to suit your scenario.